# F-crystals from crystalline cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, d-modules, crystalline-cohomology

In Section 7 of Katz' paper:

[https://web.math.princeton.edu/~nmk/old/travdwork.pdf](https://web.math.princeton.edu/%7Enmk/old/travdwork.pdf)

He asserts "Crystalline cohomology tells us that for each integer $i \geq 0$, the de Rham cohomology $H^i=Rf_*(\Omega_X/S_\infty)$ with its Gauss-Manin connection $\nabla$ is the underlying differential equation of an $F$-crystal..."

He cites a huge series of short notes by Berthelot and Berthelot's thesis but I presume by now there is a better reference. Is there a single reference where I can find a proof of this statement?

Comment: I don't have access, but I imagine Berthelot's book would be the goto: https://www.jstor.org/stable/j.ctt130hk6f

Comment: @Carlo Beenakker Do you have a Theorem number?

Comment: no, as I said, I do not have access to the book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I shall try to stick to the notation in Katz's paper. Let $k$ be a perfect field of characteristic $p>0$. Let $S_{\infty}$ be a $p$-adically complete and separated smooth formal $W(k)$-scheme and $f:X\rightarrow S_{\infty}$ a proper smooth formal $S_{\infty}$-scheme such that de Rham cohomology modules $H^{i}_{\mathrm{dR}}(X/S_{\infty}):=\mathbb{R}^{i}f_{\ast}\Omega^{\bullet}_{X/S_{\infty}}$ are locally free. Let $\nabla$ be the Gauss-Manin connection on $H^{i}_{\mathrm{dR}}(X/S_{\infty})$. Now, let $f_{1}:X_{1}\rightarrow S_{1}$ be the reduction modulo $p$ of $f:X\rightarrow S_{\infty}$. Let $\varphi_{1}:S_{1}\rightarrow S_{1}$ be the absolute Frobenius and let $\varphi:S_{\infty}\rightarrow S_{\infty}$ be a lifting of $\varphi_{1}$. Write $X'\times_{S_{\infty}}S_{\infty}$ and $X'_{1}\times_{S_{1}}S_{1}$ for the base change along $\varphi$ and $\varphi_{1}$, respectively. Let $F:X_{1}\rightarrow X_{1}'$ be the relative Frobenius. Then by functoriality we get an induced morphism (horizontal for $\nabla$)
\begin{equation*}
F:H^{i}_{\mathrm{cris}}(X'_{1}/S_{\infty})\rightarrow H^{i}_{\mathrm{cris}}(X_{1}/S_{\infty})\,.
\end{equation*}
But
\begin{equation*}
H^{i}_{\mathrm{cris}}(X'_{1}/S_{\infty})\cong H^{i}_{\mathrm{dR}}(X'/S_{\infty})\cong\varphi^{\ast}H^{i}_{\mathrm{dR}}(X/S_{\infty})
\end{equation*}
where I have used the main property of crystalline cohomology (that it computes the de Rham cohomology of a lift), base change and locally freeness. Composing with $F$ gives me a horizontal map
\begin{equation*}
F(\varphi):\varphi^{\ast}H^{i}_{\mathrm{dR}}(X/S_{\infty})\rightarrow H^{i}_{\mathrm{dR}}(X/S_{\infty})
\end{equation*}
depending on the choice of Frobenius lift $\varphi$. If $\psi$ is another lift of $\varphi_{1}$ then the connection $\nabla$ gives an isomorphism (``parallel transport'')
\begin{equation*}
\chi(\varphi,\psi):\psi^{\ast}H^{i}_{\mathrm{dR}}(X/S_{\infty})\cong H_{\mathrm{cris}}^{i}(X'_{i}/S_{\infty})\cong \varphi^{\ast} H^{i}_{\mathrm{dR}}(X/S_{\infty})\,,
\end{equation*}
and $F(\varphi)\circ\epsilon(\varphi,\psi)=F(\psi)$. Overall we get that $(H^{i}_{\mathrm{dR}}(X/S_{\infty}),\nabla, F)$ is an $F$-crystal as in (1.3) of Katz's paper. Note that $\nabla$ satisfies Griffiths transversality with respect to the Hodge filtration, so $(H^{i}_{\mathrm{dR}}(X/S_{\infty}),\nabla, \mathrm{Fil}^{\bullet}, F)$ is a filtered $F$-crystal. If the Hodge cohomology modules $H^{i}(X,\Omega_{X/S_{\infty}}^{j})$ are locally-free then $(H^{i}_{\mathrm{dR}}(X/S_{\infty}),\nabla, \mathrm{Fil}^{\bullet}, F)$ is a Hodge $F$-crystal as in 5.0 of Katz's paper.

I don't know a single reference for all of these things. Surely most of it is in P. Berthelot, *Cohomologie cristalline des sch'{e}mas de caract'{e}ristique $p>0$*, Lecture Notes in Math., Vol. 407. or the textbook that Carlo Beenakker suggested in the comments: P. Berthelot, A. Ogus, *Notes on crystalline cohomology*, Princeton University Press, Princeton, NJ, University of Tokyo Press, Tokyo, 1978. There is also Remark (2.9) in P. Berthelot, A. Ogus, *$F$-isocrystals and de Rham cohomology. I*, Invent. Math. 72 (1983), no. 2, 159–199. which might help you. For the Griffiths transversality bit see section 1.4 of N. Katz, *Algebraic solutions of differential equations ($p$-curvature and the Hodge filtration)*, Invent. Math. 18 (1972), 1–118. for a more general statement.

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful. Where can I find the statement that 
 is horizontal for ∇? Would you mind saying a few words about that? Also in a related point, how are we defining the Gauss-Manin connection on crystalline cohomology? (I'm sorry if that's a very ignorant question.)

Comment: That $F$ is horizontal is just functoriality. For the Gauss-Manin connection you can look at Katz-Oda, *On the differentiation of de Rham cohomology classes with respect to parameters.*, J. Math. Kyoto Univ. 8 (1968), 199–213. To see that the connection coming from the crystal is the same as the Gauss-Manin connection, see Chapitre V.3.6 in the Berthelot reference in my answer.